# non-numeric argument running Bootstrap in R

Tags: r, numeric, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap my data , sample of it is below

```
AveOn   AveOff  AveLd   DWELL_SEC
0.3     0.1     5.9     14
0.3     0.1     5.9     17
0.3     0.1     5.9     9
1.1     1.5    25.3     21
1.1     1.5    25.3     159
1.1     1.5    25.3     14
1.1     1.5    25.3     13
1.1     1.5    25.3     18
1.1     1.5    25.3     26
1.1     1.5    25.3     19
1.1     1.5    25.3     17
1.1     1.5    25.3     24
1.1     1.5    25.3     27
```

I wrote the following code

```
library(xlsx)
library(bootstrap)
rawData <- read.xlsx("9660.xlsx")
load<-function(AveLd,AveOff,AveOn,DWELL_SEC)sum((AveLd-AveOff)+AveOn)

bootstrap(rawData,load,10000,replace=true)
```

I kept Getting this Error

```
Error in n * nboot : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

is there a way to solve it

appreciated your time and help

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up the arguments...

```
bootstrap(rawData, func=load, nboot=10000, replace=TRUE)
```

For further information have a look at the function help

```
?bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your data:

```
rawData = structure(list(AveOn = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1), AveOff = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), AveLd = c(5.9, 5.9, 
5.9, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3, 25.3
), DWELL_SEC = c(14L, 17L, 9L, 21L, 159L, 14L, 13L, 18L, 26L, 
19L, 17L, 24L, 27L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

If you want to use the package `bootstrap`, then you bootstrap the indices of the data frame, and provide the data frame as an additional argument:

```
func = function(x,data){
with(data[x,],sum((AveLd-AveOff)+AveOn)) 
}

bootstrap(1:nrow(rawData),nboot=1000,theta=func,data=rawData)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(xlsx)
library(bootstrap)
rawData <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\TAQWA\\Downloads\\9660.xlsx",1)
#load<-function(AveLd,AveOff,AveOn,DWELL_SEC)
#  + + sum((AveLd-AveOff)+AveOn)
#bootstrap(rawData,10000,load())
three_d_array <- array(0,dim = c(270, 6, 20))
for (i in 1:20){
candy = 1:nrow(rawData)
B=sample(candy,nrow(rawData) , replace=T)
a=rawData[B,]
three_d_array[,,i]=as.matrix(a)
}
```

Comment: How does this code answer your question? Can you provide further information?

Comment: you can write help(bootstrap) and check the method that used to get the bootstrap method.

Comment: you never use the `bootstrap` method... I really can't find out how your answer actually answers your question

Comment: now bootstrap use to talk random sampling, using different number of arrays, in the same token three-d-arry works the same concept